# this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key currentLetter

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I keep getting a SIGABRT error and the bellow error in console:

TraceViewController 0x7fb03a116900> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key currentLetter

I have tried everything, there are no incorrect outlets. I checked the source of the view and currentLetter does not exist anywhere. I tried deleting Derived Data and rebuilding the project. There is a variable in TraceViewController called currentLetter and also change all of those to cLetter and I still get exactly the same error saying currentLetter. I can't find currentLetter anywhere in my project but keep getting it.

Im not really sure what code to upload its a bit difficult to show, any idea what I could do to solve it though?

Update:

I don't think it has to do with an unconnected outlet, im pretty sure I have found the issue somewhere below:

I have a file called letterTableViewCell2.swift that has this code:

```
class letterTableViewCell2: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var letter2: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var letter1: UIButton!


@IBAction func tapAction1(_ sender: Any) {
    var a = "a"
    a = letter1.currentTitle!
    let shareVC = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "TraceViewController") as!TraceViewController
    shareVC.currentLetter = a

    viewController().parent?.setValue(a, forKey: "currentLetter")
    viewController().parent?.viewDidLoad()

    print(shareVC.currentLetter)
}
```

Then in my TraceViewController I have a variable:

```
public var currentLetter
```

I have checked the list of Outlets in my storyboard files and there is no reference to currentLetter

Comment: Remove `viewController().parent?.setValue(a, forKey: "currentLetter")
    viewController().parent?.viewDidLoad()`

Comment: @matt No. `viewController().parent?.setValue(a, forKey: "currentLetter")` is the reason for crash

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the below lines

```
viewController().parent?.setValue(a, forKey: "currentLetter")
viewController().parent?.viewDidLoad()
```

You shouldn't try to open `TraceViewController` from the cell class `letterTableViewCell2`

1. You can use delegate to open `TraceViewController` from the view controller which contains the tableview
2. Or you can use closure to open `TraceViewController` from the view controller which contains the tableview
3. Or you can add `IBAction` for the button in view controller class

**Using delegate**

//letterTableViewCell2.swift

```
protocol LetterTableViewCell2Delegate: class {
    func letter1Tapped(letter: String)
}

class letterTableViewCell2: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var letter2: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var letter1: UIButton!
    weak var delegate: LetterTableViewCell2Delegate?

    @IBAction func tapAction1(_ sender: Any) {
        var a = "a"
        a = letter1.currentTitle!
        delegate?.letter1Tapped(letter: a)
    }
}
```

//ViewController.swift

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    ///
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell") as? letterTableViewCell2 else {
            fatalError("Cell not registered")
        }
        cell.delegate = self
        return cell
    }
}
extension ViewController: LetterTableViewCell2Delegate {
    func letter1Tapped(letter: String) {
        let shareVC = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "TraceViewController") as! TraceViewController
        shareVC.currentLetter = letter
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(shareVC, animated: true)
    }
}
```

Comment: how would I go about doing the delegate option for this? I have been looking through answers on stack exchange but pretty lost :/

Answer (score 0):

Since you have renamed the outlets, there must be an issue of connection. 
Open storyboard, Go to Inspector and cross check the Referencing Outlets if you can disconnect and connect them again.

I hope this may help you!

Comment: Hey mate, no I don't think it is an unconnected outlet. I only change the currentLetter variable to cLetter to see if the error still showed up, it was still giving me the error before I changed it. I have updated my question as I think I found the source of the issue.

Comment: Okay. What is the data type of variable currentLetter?

Comment: It is set as a string, so that would be why. Im working through a previous teams project, not sure why they set it like that when it isn't a dictionary. What should I change it to?

Comment: Keep it as "String" data type only. No need to change anything. I believe you need to reverse engineer the code, if you can try commenting out the two code lines before print and see if it works or not.

Answer (score 0):

Select your ViewController in storyboard.
Right click on yellow dot .
Find yellow warnings ⚠️ if exist.
Delete(click on cross button) those connections.
Build and run your project.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hey mate, im not getting any warnings in the storyboard. I have updated my question as I think I found the source of the problem.